# List of available wifi networks is empty

Tags: wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

I struggle to get my wifi up and running on `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS` with kernel `6.2.0-35-generic`.

While the wifi pretends to be up and running:

```
nmcli d
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION         
enxea7f95cf8ba0  ethernet  connected     Wired connection 3 
wlp6s0           wifi      disconnected  --                 
p2p-dev-wlp6s0   wifi-p2p  disconnected  --                 
enp4s0           ethernet  unavailable   --                 
enp5s0           ethernet  unavailable   --                 
lo               loopback  unmanaged     --
```

and the wifi adapter seems to be identified correctly

```
lshw -class network

*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 1a
       serial: 08:5b:d6:cd:ef:88
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.2.0-35-generic firmware=72.daa05125.0 cc-a0-72.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:40 memory:fc600000-fc603fff
```

and the driver is loaded without any errors

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    4.198591] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.204009] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    4.204021] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    4.204594] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: loaded firmware version 72.daa05125.0 cc-a0-72.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.305199] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    4.432221] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected RF HR B3, rfid=0x10a100
[    4.496487] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: base HW address: 08:5b:d6:cd:ef:88
[    4.512116] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0 wlp6s0: renamed from wlan0
```

no networks are detected: There are no networks listed in the graphical network manager and `nmcli device wifi list` returns an empty list, even though there are a dozen wifi networks in the vicinity.

I am unsure what to do from here? What am I missing?